# Copy to move promotion

Tags: c++, move-semantics

I asked a similar question on [langdev.stackexchange.com](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/questions/1876/automatic-copy-to-move-promotion), but I think it also fits here.

C++ compilers may (or must?) generate a call to the move constructor of `X` instead of the copy constructor in the return statement in the following example:

```cpp
struct X { /*...*/ };

X f(X x) { return x; }
```

Now consider this code:

```
void f() {
    X a;
    X b = a; // Must call the copy constructor, not the move constructor
    // More code that provably does not use or reference a
}
```

I wonder why C++ does not allow more general copy to move transformations like in this example, if it can prove that the copied from object is not used anymore.
I know that the transformation would possibly change the semantics of the code, but so does the transformation in the previous example and so does return value optimization in general. So the standard seems to be fine with eliding copy constructors even if they have side effects.

Is it just that nobody has proposed this yet? Or are there any pitfalls with such a transformation that don't apply to RVO? Or would it simply make the language more complex and confusing than it already is?

Comment: As an example, what set of minimal rules would you propose where the implicit move would apply? Or do you just want to give the compiler the option to replace a copy with a move if it can prove that the object isn't accessed after the move, but not make any such implicit move mandatory?

Comment: @user17732522 Yes, I would propose that the compiler be free to replace the copy by a move if it _can_ prove that the object is not used anymore. I know that this can't be proven in every case where it's true, but in many simple cases like forwarding constructor arguments we wouldn't have to move explicitly.

Comment: A copy constructor and a move constructor may have different side effects that are almost always unknown to a compiler if they are not implemented in a header file. Therefore a compiler may not assume that an implicit move is equivalent of a copy.

Comment: *but in many simple cases* Later you add a few new code lines and the existing code behavior changes significantly. The mentioned copy elision doesn't change the existing code behavior if you add a new code.

Comment: @chrysante There is currently no other construct in the language where the compiler can decide whether a copy or move constructor is called instead. Return value optimizations can only completely eliminate either and these exception have been there since the first C++ standard edition. My feeling is that one would have to have a very good reason to introduce such an additional complication to the language.

Comment: @273K But isn't the implicit move in return statements also optional? There the problem with the changed semantics also occurs, so it seems the C++ standard is at least to some degree willing to accept it.

Comment: @chrysante No, the implicit move in a return statement is fully specified. The compiler has no freedom to choose.

Comment: No, return statement behavior is fully specified and a new code doesn't change it. Whereas `X b = a;` behavior with your proposal must be changed if a new code references `a`.

Comment: @chrysante Also, when the implicit move in `return` statements was introduced there wasn't yet any user-defined move operations, so backwards-compatibility was less of an issue. Now you have to take into account that such a rule change may affect the behavior of programs that use not-so-well-behaved move operations. Not that this means it would be impossible, but something that needs to be considered. There have been small extensions to the implicit move rule though, see e.g. https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2266r3.html#biblio-p1155 for the most recent one.

Comment: @user17732522 Yes, I do see the point. But can you come up with any sane program that would break under such a transformation? I couldn't think of any. Probably another problem is that most existing compilers have their code analysis phases in the backend which is agnostic of copy or move constructors, so it would require major changes to implement the feature.

Comment: @chrysante Maybe something like `auto x = std::make_shared<A>(); B b{x.get()}; f(x);` where `f` takes a `std::shared_ptr<A>` by-value and where `B` stores a reference to somewhere in `A` and uses that in its destructor, assuming that the lifetime of `x` assures the lifetime of this reference. With your suggestion this will become undefined behavior because you shorten the lifetime of `A`. (Except if you would require lifetime verifications recursively for objects referenced in the potentially-moved object, but then it becomes even less practical.)

Comment: @user17732522 That would be a case where the implicit move should not apply, but tbh I have no idea how to detect the escaped pointer to the storage of the `shared_ptr` object in general. It seems the whole thing is not as simple as I thought it would be.

Answer (score 2):

Consider that your example might continue

```
struct X {
    std::shared_ptr<int> p = std::make_shared<int>();
};
void f() {
    X a;
    int &i = *a.p;
    X b = a;
    {X c(std::move(b);}
    ++i;
}
```

`i` ought to still be valid so long as `a` is, but with such an implicit move `a`’s **value** would have perished with `c`.